# Как в css использовать html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть код который возвращает цвет:

```
var stringToColor = function stringToColor(str) {
    var hash = 0;
    var color = '#';
    var i;
    var value;
    var strLength;

    if (!str) {
        return color + '333333';
    }

    strLength = str.length;

    for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {
        hash = str.charCodeAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
        color += ('00' + value.toString(16)).substr(-2);
    }
    return color;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="user-info-avatar" style="background-color:stringToColor('n')">name</div>
```

Как сделать в css чтобы установить bacground-color?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала вам нужно найти DOM-элемент на странице, который вы хотите поменять. Например, это можно сделать при помощи метода document.querySelector(".user-info-avatar"); В скобочках указывается CSS-селектор элемента, такой же, какой вы пишете в таблице стилей.

После того, как вы найдёте нужный элемент, его стилевые свойства можно изменить при помощи свойства style. При этом, названия свойств нужно писать не через тире, а при помощи calmalCase. Например:

```
let el = document.querySelector(".querySelector");

el.style.backgroundColor = stringToColor
```

Answer (score 0):

из css это вряд ли получится это делается из js
В вашем случае как то так

```
document.getElementsByClassName("user-info-avatar").style.backgroundColor = stringToColor('n');
```

Comment: Это решение не подходит, если у меня список и для каждого элемента списка будет свой backgroundColor